# PhP script to know the current URL

Tags: php

The duplicate question deals with .htaccess issue. I deal with the fact that /index.php may or may not be part of original URL

One way to do so is to do

```
http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

The problem is if URL is `http://domainname.com` the

```
http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

will yield

```
http://domainname.com/index.php
```

instead.

I need something that yield `http://domainname.com`

Comment: And why don't you just use `http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` then?

Comment: The linked duplicate uses `REQUEST_URI` instead of `PHP_SELF`. It also includes a bunch of other methods that work with proxy forwarding.

Comment: Because I want to show http://domainname.com/hello/bla.bla.php when users indeed access http://domainname.com/hello/bla.bla.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to user HTTP_HOST for your current host name :-

```
http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```